# C++ False Function Pointer Equivalence

Tags: c++, pointers

So the problem I have is quite convoluted yet important. I can't tell if this is a  feature of C++ or a compiler feature. But what's happening is that two different function from different classes are getting the same address:

```
//-- My Code --//
class A {
public:
    int myFunc() {
        return 3;
    }
};


//-- Other Code --//
namespace glm{
namespace detail
{
    template <typename T>
    GLM_FUNC_QUALIFIER typename tvec3<T>::size_type tvec3<T>::length() const
    {
        return 3;
    }

    //... Omitted
}
}

//-- Test --//
TypelessMember::Func<int> funcOverridenA = TypelessMember::func(&A::myFunc); // The original function pointer (pretending to be a member function of a "typeless" class)
auto equivalenceFunc = &glm::detail::tvec3<unsigned char>::length; // Get the false equivalence member function pointer
auto equivalence = *(TypelessMember::Func<int>*)&equivalenceFunc; // Pretend that this is a different type of function
if (equivalence == funcOverridenA) {
    puts("False function equivalence"); // This block of code is hit
    return false;
}


//-- Other test --//
A valueA = {};
TypelessMember* typelessA = typeless(&valueA);
int v = (typelessA->*funcOverridenA)(); // This calls the glm function (I guess because it was produced in the PCH first)
```

Obviously, I do not want a function pointer to A::myFunc to be equivalent to a function pointer to glm's length function. So what do I do? Can this be avoided somehow? I am mainly concerned because I want to be able to have two unique function pointers.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Almost none of the identifiers you use actually are defined in the question. What is `TypelessMember`?

Comment: Though probably the real answer is that you're attempting to compare two things of different types (pointers to members of different classes)... you somehow munged it into compiling, but it's still undefined behavior.

Comment: I know it's pretty undefined. I gave as minimalistic of a question I could (I omitted junk and placed descriptions in the comments). I don't expect anyone to actually try and run my code since it requires many compiler hacks and workarounds, so I just provided results in the comments as well.

Comment: If you know it's undefined, why are you asking about specific perceived behavior? Undefined behavior is undefined.

Comment: I care because in the end, I am producing a product that has quantifiable and measurable (perceivable) behavior. It's not ponies and unicorns that I'm after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known problem with the MS compiler. When they remove "unneded" copies of functions, like instantiated templates, they look at what the function contains, not their names.

You have two functions taking no parameters and returning the value 3. They will of course generate exactly the same code. And the linker will just keep one copy, believing that nobody wants identical copies of some code.

Comment: I bet there's a linker option to turn that off.

Comment: Ok, thank you... so it is a compiler thing. I'm guessing the C++ standard says nothing about what to do in this case?

Comment: @DarthZaloj - The standard says that the addresses *have* to be different, but MS doesn't claim to be 100% conformant...